# What Items Can be Combined and What Items are Safe to Sell in RE4?

Tags: resident-evil-4-2005

I understand that all treasure is there to be sold to get more gold.  However, I also, know that some of the treasures can be combined to make items that can be sold for even MORE gold.  What items can be combined, and what items can be sold as is to maximize profit?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Treasure

Here are all the treasures that you can find in Resident Evil 4 and how much they will get you from the merchant.  Some of them can be combined in order to make items that will get you **more** money.  Some items are found close to each other while some span the entire game.

## Combine

These are the items that you can combine together in order to get **more** money.  The number next to the top item in the list is the amount you'll get if you are patient enough to combine all the pieces together while the sub-items are the components you need and the money you'll get if you sell the piece individually.

**Crown** (48,000Pts)

- Royal Insignia (13,000Pts)
- Crown Jewel (11,000Pts)

**Golden Lynx** (35,000Pts)

- Blue Stone of Treason (3,500Pts)
- Green Stone of Judgement (3,500Pts)
- Red Stone of Faith (3,500Pts)

**Butterfly Lamp** (32,000Pts)

- Blue Eye (3,000Pts)
- Red Eye (1,500Pts)
- Green Eye (1,000Pts)

**Beerstein** (20,000Pts)

- Green Catseye (3,000Pts)
- Red Catseye (3,000Pts)
- Yellow Catseye (3,000Pts)

**Elegant Mask**  (20,000Pts)

- Red Gem (3,000Pts)
- Green Gem (3,000Pts)
- Purple Gem (3,000Pts)

## Stand Alone

These are the treasures that you find that don't combine together.  You are safe to sell them as you find them because they don't appreciate in value (besides the dirty items that can only *depreciate* in value).

#### Gems

These treasures are found numerously throughout the game and don't join with other items.

- Ruby (10,000Pts)
- Emerald (3,000Pts)
- Velvet Blue (2,500Pts)
- Spinel (2,000Pts)

#### Fragile

These items can be worth less than normal if you let them fall into the water.

- Pearl Pendant (10,000Pts) / Dirty (1,000Pts)
- Brass Pocket Watch (10,000Pts) / Dirty (1,000Pts)

#### Artifacts

Although not as plentiful as Gems, they still don't combine so feel free to sell them.

- Staff of Royalty (20,000Pts)
- Elegant Chessboard (13,000Pts)
- Mirror with Pearls and Rubies (12,000Pts)
- Hourglass with Gold Decor (12,000Pts)
- Illuminados Pendant (12,000Pts)
- Elegant Headdress (10,000Pts)
- Amber Ring (10,000Pts)
- Antique Pipe (10,000Pts)
- Gold Bangle with Pearls (10,000Pts)
- Elegant Perfume Bottle (10,000Pts)
- Gold Bangle (8,500Pts)